# PHP - redirect page to URL without protocol?

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

I'm in trouble and not sure how to resolve this problem.

I have a website `www.example.com`. It's being opened on mobile browsers and I have to do a redirect to `something://` after one action triggers redirect.

No matter how hard I try I can never redirect to `something://`, when I do:

`<?php header('Location: something://'); ?>` what I'm getting is: `http://www.example.com/something://`.

I've been trying with JS (location.replace.href, location.replace etc.) with no luck as well.

How do I force URL to change the way I EXACTLY want?

Comment: Could you show the headers from your redirect HTTP response?

Comment: I'm doing this on mobile devices, so can't really debug it :(

Comment: You always could sniff the traffic using `wireshark` or similar software.

Comment: does it work in a desktop browser?

Comment: @thelastshadow it should

Comment: Also, try to use `header('Location: something://somedomain/somepath/')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) says:

> Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI

where `absoluteURI` is specified in [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396).

```
  absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )
  relativeURI   = ( net_path | abs_path | rel_path ) [ "?" query ]

  hier_part     = ( net_path | abs_path ) [ "?" query ]
  opaque_part   = uric_no_slash *uric

  uric_no_slash = unreserved | escaped | ";" | "?" | ":" | "@" |
                  "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","

  net_path      = "//" authority [ abs_path ]
  abs_path      = "/"  path_segments

  authority     = server | reg_name

  reg_name      = 1*( unreserved | escaped | "$" | "," |
                      ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" )

  server        = [ [ userinfo "@" ] hostport ]
  userinfo      = *( unreserved | escaped |
                     ";" | ":" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | "," )

  hostport      = host [ ":" port ]
  host          = hostname | IPv4address
  hostname      = *( domainlabel "." ) toplabel [ "." ]
  domainlabel   = alphanum | alphanum *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
  toplabel      = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
  IPv4address   = 1*digit "." 1*digit "." 1*digit "." 1*digit
  port          = *digit
```

From this, if you are using a `something://` protocol, you need to specify the `authority` part - the slashes cannot be the last part of the string, e.g. `something://example`

However, the final call on where to redirect is always with the client's browser, which may refuse to redirect to non-HTTP(S) URLs for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for JavaScript solution, try the following:

```
window.location = 'customprotocol://';
window.location.assign('customprotocol://');
```

But if your app (i.e. there's nothing associated with `customprotocol://`) isn't installed, is most likely to see nothing. The common solution to that problem is to provide fallback mechanism with `setTimeout`, so if there's nothing associated with `customprotocol://`, just redirect user to any available page after specified amount of time.

```
window.location = 'customprotocol://';
window.setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'http://example.com/fallback.html' }, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the JS method shown by @vitozev,
or:

```
echo <<< EOF
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=something://">
EOF;
```

or:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: something://');
header ('Content-Length: 0');
```